# Returning views as data - Node/express

Tags: node.js, express

In codeigniter, it's possible:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', TRUE);
```

The parameter TRUE lets you change the behavior of the method so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser.

But with **Express**, it's possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using javascript? and what is the engine and/or extension of your view file?

Comment: Chanturidze, Im with ejs view engine in Nodejs with express.

Comment: See https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express and http://ejs.co/#install. Essentially, you'd call `ejs.render` directly, which is what Express is doing behind the scenes when it renders a page.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!